# TDs background color not visible in print preview

Tags: html, css, browser, printing

I have td like this:

```
<td align="left" bgcolor="#FF0000">
```

In browsers, there is a red background color applied to it but when i see print preview of this, there is no red color in the background. also the font color is white but it also gets converted to white when print previewing it.

Anyone knows what can be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printing of background colors is supported differently by each browser, and it is often off by default. For instance, in [Safari](http://apple.com/safari), it is an option in the print dialog called "Print Backgrounds". I am not sure where the option is in other browsers.

Answer (score 12):

To make WebKit browsers (Safari, Google Chrome) print the background image or color you should add the following css style to the element:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue myself and believe I have a solution. I originally did this with an H1 tag but then used the same code for a TD

```
h1 {
    background-color:#404040;
    background-image:url("img/404040.png");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #404040;
    border:30px solid #404040;
    height:0;
    width:100%;
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    margin:0 -20px;
    line-height:0px;
}
```

Here are a couple things to note:

- background-color is the absolute fallback and is there for posterity mostly.
- background-image uses a 1px x 1px pixel of #404040 made into a PNG. If the user has images enabled it may work, if not...
- Set the box-shadow, if that doesn't work...
- Border = 1/2 your desired height and/or width of box, solid, color. In the example above I wanted a 60px height box.
- Zero out the heigh/width depending on what you're controlling in the border attribute.
- Font color will default to black unless you use !important
- Set line-height to 0 to fix for the box not having physical dimension.
- Make and host your own damn PNGs ;)

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buttonpresser/vqxMA/) for a more detailed demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS if you can and if the background doesn't work with the print version specify a print css document.

`<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`

Basic CSS here:

`td{
background-color:#FF0000;
}`

Comment: As mentioned by @doug-neiner this doesn't work across all browsers, just doing the CSS won't work

Comment: I don't see any mention of CSS by @doug-neiner . The OP was also asking about font-color when printing. You marked this down?

Comment: This doesn't work. Both Chrome and FF ignore CSS background colors when printing.